# PHP : login intrigation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook sdk for login into my site...

This is my app setting

[image]

when I used login functionality, it allow to login but throws error and doesn't back to my site
The error is like this...

```
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.:
One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.
It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

What can be problem?

Help me

Answer (score 0):

You should add your App domain to **App Domains** to your Facebook Application configuration shown in the screenshot. For example if your site is

> www.example.com

The your should add

> example.com

to your **App Domains** in your configuration (4th field from top to bottom)